# Solana wallet adapter access wallet automatically

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

Is there a way to connect to a wallet automatically using public keypair, then store credentials for future use without user required to give permission every time?

Comment: What do you mean connect to a wallet automatically?

Comment: for instance connect from a python script

Comment: There currently is not a wallet-adapter for python